# Ansible code written in YAML format that can be used to remove MySQL and Java from an Ubuntu system?

Tags: java, mysql, ubuntu, ansible, yaml

I have used Ansible YAML code to install MySQL and Java on different servers. However, I now want to remove/uninstall MySQL and Java from those same servers. I have attempted to do so using code, but the software still appears to be running and installed on the target machines.

I have tried below codes.

```
---
- hosts: [dbservers]
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Uninstall MySQL
      shell: apt remove mysql-server -y
- hosts: [appservers]
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Uninstall java
      shell: apt remove openjdk-17-jre -y
```

&

```
---
- hosts: [dbservers]
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Uninstall MySQL
      apt:
        name: mysql-server
        state: absent
- hosts: [appservers]
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Uninstall Java
      apt:
        name: openjdk-17-jre
        state: absent
```

I'm getting same output for both codes.

```
PLAY [dbservers] ****************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************
ok: [172.31.81.148]

TASK [Uninstall MySQL] **********************************************************************
changed: [172.31.81.148]

PLAY [appservers] ***************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************
ok: [172.31.26.22]

TASK [Uninstall java] ***********************************************************************
changed: [172.31.26.22]

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************
172.31.26.22               : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
172.31.81.148              : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

ubuntu@ip-172-31-19-201:~/AnsibleCodes$
```

Anyone have working(correct) YAML code for this?

Comment: first skip the ansible part and manually test your apt commands?

Comment: you might just want e.g.`apt remove mysql-server --purge --autoremove -y`

Comment: Before asking for "working" code (which is clearly an off-topic demand here), are you able to [describe precisely what does "not work"](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)? Your second playbook is rather on the good track using available Ansible modules and the output seems to indicate it did the exact job you asked for.